# how to type transition props in material ui popper

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, typescript-typings

I am using material ui [popper](https://material-ui.com/components/popper/) and want to separate the transition into a separate function as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles, Theme, createStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Popper from '@material-ui/core/Popper';
import Fade from '@material-ui/core/Fade';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    paper: {
      border: '1px solid',
      padding: theme.spacing(1),
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    },
  }),
);

export default function TransitionsPopper() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(anchorEl ? null : event.currentTarget);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? 'transitions-popper' : undefined;

  const popperTrans = ({ TransitionProps }) => (
    <Fade {...TransitionProps} timeout={350}>
      <div className={classes.paper}>The content of the Popper.</div>
    </Fade>
  )
  return (
    <div>
      <button aria-describedby={id} type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Toggle Popper
      </button>
      <Popper id={id} open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl} transition>
        {popperTrans}
      </Popper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am using typescript and it's throwing tslint error `Binding element 'TransitionProps' implicitly has an 'any' type`. How can I type `TransitionProps` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, `TransitionProps` is exported, so you can do:

```
import { TransitionProps as TransitionPropsType } from "@material-ui/core";
```

Then:

```
  const popperTrans = ({ TransitionProps }: { TransitionProps: TransitionPropsType }) => (
    <Fade {...TransitionProps} timeout={350}>
      <div className={classes.paper}>The content of the Popper.</div>
    </Fade>
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. We can import `FadeProps` from `Fade` and use that to type `TransitionProps`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles, Theme, createStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Popper from '@material-ui/core/Popper';
import Fade, { FadeProps } from '@material-ui/core/Fade';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    paper: {
      border: '1px solid',
      padding: theme.spacing(1),
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    },
  }),
);

export default function TransitionsPopper() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(anchorEl ? null : event.currentTarget);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? 'transitions-popper' : undefined;

  const popperTrans = ({ TransitionProps }: { TransitionProps: FadeProps }) => (
    <Fade {...TransitionProps} timeout={350}>
      <div className={classes.paper}>The content of the Popper.</div>
    </Fade>
  )
  return (
    <div>
      <button aria-describedby={id} type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Toggle Popper
      </button>
      <Popper id={id} open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl} transition>
        {popperTrans}
      </Popper>
    </div>
  );
}
```